# Displaying multiple @Html.ActionLink in same line

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

How can I display 2 Html Action Links in a same line, that are using different action from a different controller? My code is:

```
<th>@Html.ActionLink((item.Name + " & "), "Index", "Wedding") @Html.ActionLink("Invite Partner", "InvitePartner", "Account")</th>
```

With this both actions are displayed in a different paragraph. How can I display them in a same paragraph?

EDIT:
It is all about the style, I've added bootstrap classes, and it is showing as buttons in same paragraph:

```
<th>@Html.ActionLink((item.Name + " & "), "Index", "Wedding", new { @class = "btn btn-default"}) @Html.ActionLink("Invite Partner", "InvitePartner", "Account", new { @class = "btn btn-danger"})</th>
```

Comment: They're not in different paragraphs. Probably your <th> is not wide enough to hold them and puts them on different lines. Try styling your table by setting a bigger width on the columns.

Comment: try to modifiy your css

Comment: Have you tried `&nbsp;` in between each Action link ?